# Pushing data into kafka using rest api and kafka connect

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is there a way for me to expose a rest api to which systems can push data to, which in turn creates topics and updates the avro schema registry without manually writing a custom connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can write an HTTP server in any language you're comfortable with and wrap KafkaProducer with Avro serializer and AdminClient to create topics.

The Confluent REST Proxy already does this, partially.

Kafka Connect doesn't accept records over HTTP, anyway, so a custom connector wouldn't do any good.

Comment: To check if i understood right.  
1. Create a http server in any language (python for example)  
2. Use a kafka sdk to connect to the kafka cluster to create and push data to topics.  
3. Update the avro registry based on the data for a specific topic.  
4. Use any sink connector to read data from these topics.

Comment: Sounds correct, but 3 - that'd be automatic with Avro serializer if you use confluent-kafka Python library